# Как сделать суммирование в карточке при прибавлении и убавлении времени?

Tags: jquery

На странице есть несколько блоков,каждый разный, в блоке прибавляется по часу и сумма снизу суммируется и т.д., далее отправляется формой обратной связи.
Вот код который прибавляет и убавляет, не могу сделать так, чтобы еще и к сумме прибавлялось.

```
$('.down').click(function () {
        var $input = $(this).parent().find('input');
        var count = parseInt($input.val()) - 1;
        count = count < 1 ? 1 : count;
        $input.val(count);
        $input.change();
        return false;

    });
    $('.up').click(function () {
        var $input = $(this).parent().find('input');
        $input.val(parseInt($input.val()) + 1);
        $input.change();
        return false;
    });
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.down').click(function () {
        var $input = $(this).parent().find('input');
        var count = parseInt($input.val()) - 1;
        count = count < 1 ? 1 : count;
        $input.val(count);
        $input.change();
        $('#id').html($input.val() * 500); // id заменить на селлектор того блока где выводим цену, А 500 на ставку за час
        return false;

    });
    $('.up').click(function () {
        var $input = $(this).parent().find('input');
        $input.val(parseInt($input.val()) + 1);
        $input.change();
        $('#id').html($input.val() * 500); // Аналогично
        return false;
    });
```

А если используется несколько блоков и надо применить именно к конкретному то в зависимости от разметки меняем примерно так:

```
 $(this).parent().find('#id').html($input.val() * 500); // Получаем родителя для кнопки по которой кликнули и в нем ищем элемент где выводится цена
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let $calc = $('.calc');

$('body').click(function (event) { // т.к. блоков много, начинаем с прослушмвания клика но боди
  let $t = $(event.target);
  if (event.target.className == 'button-calc') { // кликнули ли мы по кнопке +/-
    let sign = event.target.value;
    let $wrapper = $(event.target).closest('.calc'), // ищем обёртку этой кнопки и дальше работаем от неё
      $amount = $wrapper.find('.amount'), // оределяем элемент с суммой
      amountInit = parseInt($wrapper.find('.amount-init').html()), // определяем тег начальной суммой
      finalAmount = parseInt($amount.html()), // определяем сумму
      $qty = $wrapper.find('.qty'), // определяем элемент с количеством
      qty = parseInt($qty.html());
    if (sign == '-') { // считаем
      finalAmount = parseInt($amount.html()) - amountInit;
      qty--;
    } else {
      finalAmount = parseInt($amount.html()) + amountInit;
      qty++;
    }
    $amount.html((finalAmount < amountInit) ? amountInit : finalAmount); // подставляем
    $qty.html((qty < 1) ? 1 : qty);
  }
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="calc">
  <div class="info">Стоимость <span class="amount-init">500</span><span class="currency"> руб.</span></div>
  <input type="button" class="button-calc" value="-" />
  <div><span class="qty">1</span>&nbsp;x&nbsp;<span class="amount">500</span><span class="currency"> руб.</span></div>
  <input type="button" class="button-calc" value="+" />
</div>
```